# can boost::managed_shared_memory handle vector correctly?

Tags: c++, vector, boost, stl

Here is the official example to use vector in shared memory between processes:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container

However I still have some concern:

1. what if the vector need to reallocate new memory(e.g. after several push_back)?
2. what if the vector keep increasing and finally consume all the initialized memory?
3. what's the performance penalty by comparing with the original STL vector?

Comment: Don't want to push my own answers, but I have /many/ answers using Boost Interprocess showing the fine edges of using (scoped/cascading) allocators to do all this correctly for your  (nested) (container) classes

Comment: @sehe I found them: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:85371+[boost-interprocess]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It does so via the custom `ShmemAllocator`. That's how allocators work: you swap out the standard heap-allocator that calls `new` for Boost's one that allocates from the shared memory segment.
2. Same behaviour as running out of memory with the standard allocator: an exception will be thrown (not `std::bad_alloc` though: it's [apparently](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-managed-shared-memory) `boost::interprocess::bad_alloc` instead).
3. You'll want to benchmark the Boost's allocator's allocation speed, and compare it with that of `std::allocator`, which is the default. The vector itself does not really matter.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 separate entities here

1. Vector
2. Allocator

When you create `vector` as

```
vector <int> v1;
```

It is actually

```
vector<int, allocator<int>> v1;
```

We don't provide any memory allocator because its the defult allocator.

Now in the case of `Boost.Interprocess` communication, the vector is created as

```
typedef vector<int, ShmemAllocator> MyVector
```

Where the memory allocator is changed to Shared Memory Allocator from Default Allocator.

So, the functionality of vector is independent of which memory allocator one uses.

Regarding the questions, the availability of memory and speed of the allocation depends upon allocators and not on vectors, as long as allocators manage to get some memory, vectors will continue to perform.

Comment: Technically, Boost.Interprocess `boost::interprocess::vector<T>` is a typedef of `boost::container::vector<T, boost::interprocess::allocator<T>>` (not `std::vector<T, bip::allocator<T>>`). I think the STL vectors is not customizable enough to handle offset pointers `offset_ptr`.